# Vue 3 and Vite - useRoute

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-router, vite

i use vite and vue. want to use useRoute, i want url request to interact with api, I get errors, and the router stops working in the application

[image]

[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors . The warnings say what's wrong. The router wasn't properly set up, so you can't normally use useRoute. In case the problem persists, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve